# WSO2 EI Rest API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.5.0 - Rest API

1. Problem was occured When i switch to source view of API
2. It shows nothing when add some mediator (payload, log resources)

[image: When i switch to source view of API]

[image]

This is LOG file(console)
[image]

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Noo, i separated REST API xml into different sequences, it worked properly.
i think error occured when i add payload mediator contains XML message in insequence

Answer (score 0):

It seems, this error comes when we switch the hostname to localhost while using the web application.
Can you try with the same hostname as on which the server stated on?
For example, since the below server started on the ip **172.17.0.1**, try with the following url (instead of localhost).

https://**172.17.0.1**:9443/carbon/api/sourceview_api.jsp?ordinal=1&mode=edit&apiName=UserInfoRestAPI&apiContext=/userInfo&hostname=&port=&version=&versionType=

[image]